# Is there a way to play a video inside an <img> tag using SVGs?

Tags: image, svg, html5-video

Note: This is a pretty unique problem, and I am not sure if this is even possible to solve.

Problem is, I need to embed a video file in a web page. I have the limitation that I can only set the `src` of an `<img>` tag, and need to embed a video that way.

Playing a video in an SVG itself is possible like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="300">
<foreignObject width="400" height="300">
    <video xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="400" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <source src="data:video/mp4;base64,${content}"></source>
    </video>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

That itself works (see the [demo](https://staging.cohostcdn.org/attachment/92a3340c-0714-4fde-84f2-a8992d728ff2/video.svg)), but if I include it in an `<img>` tag, this happens:

> [image]

(Screenshot in case it doesn't work on your browser: )

[image]

Is there a way to fix that, or is that just impossible? If it is limited by something, where can I read up on that limitation?

Comment: (If I do not find any solution I have to use a lot of PNGs in an animation, which is terrible, but I have to if there's no other way)

Comment: Images are not interactive so the video won't play.

Comment: @lxhom: you might convert your movie to an animated gif.  Admittedly not great, but maybe the only feasible workaround.

Comment: _"I have the limitation that I can only set the `src` of an `<img>` tag"_ Why is that? I wonder if there is a workaround like dynamically adding a video by javascript. The more info you give, about the "why not" situation, the better...

Comment: It's a bit complicated, but I need to post this on a website that only allows inline CSS, <img> and a few other tags. No JavaScript, no <svg>, just <img> is useful here.